# Overloading the + operator for combining two dictionaries that use vectors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, stdvector

I am a beginner at C++ and I have been trying to figure this out for a while and I can't figure out these errors.

What I need to do is overload the + operator for a class I made called Dictionary. Dictionary uses vectors to store key/value pairs which I made a class Pair that I posted here:

```
class Pair {
    private:
    string key;
    int value;
    public: 
    Pair(string k="", int v=0){key=k; value=v;};//should we be allowed to have 0,0 pairs?
    ~Pair(){};
    string getKey(){return key;};
    int getValue(){return value;};

};
```

Here is my Dictionary class and overloading of the + operator:

```
class Dictionary{
    std::vector<Pair> dic;
public:
    Dictionary(){};
    ~Dictionary(){};
Dictionary operator +(const Dictionary &vec2){
    Dictionary combined;
    combined.dic.reserve( combined.dic.size() + vec2.dic.size() ); // preallocate memory
    combined.dic.insert( combined.dic.end(), combined.dic.begin(), combined.dic.end() );
    combined.dic.insert( combined.dic.end(), vec2.dic.begin(), vec2.dic.end() );
    //dic.insert( dic.end(), vec2.dic.begin(), vec2.dic.end() );
    if (unique( combined.dic.begin(), combined.dic.end() )){
        return combined;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"ERROR: the dictionaries each contain the same key!"<<endl;       
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when I add two Dictionaries together using +, they will combine into one large Dictionary if there are no duplicate key/value pairs. (that is what the unique is for) If there are duplicates then don't add them but just print out an error.

When I compile I get this error from algorithm.cc:
"/opt/local/solstudio12.2/prod/include/CC/Cstd/algorithm.cc", line 205: Error: The operation "Pair == Pair" is illegal.
"/opt/local/solstudio12.2/prod/include/CC/Cstd/algorithm", line 482:     Where: While instantiating "std::adjacent_find(Pair*, Pair*)".
"/opt/local/solstudio12.2/prod/include/CC/Cstd/algorithm", line 482:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
1 Error(s) detected.

Could I have some advice on how to resolve this and solve this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like a `map` would be much more suitable than `vector`, at least to me.

Comment: That overloaded `operator!=` seems weird to me, as you check for *equality* in it, not inequality.

Comment: Hi Joachim, I removed the operator!= and I am still getting the same errors. I didn't call that operator != so for the time being it isn't giving me a problem. I can't get the + operator for Dictionary correct, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe you need to write a `operator ==` for `Pair`?

Comment: This line seems a bit weird `combined.dic.insert( combined.dic.end(), combined.dic.begin(), combined.dic.end() );` You might want to insert `dic` instead of `combined.dic`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique` calls the element's `operator==` to decide if elements are the same. You need to define `operator==` for `Pair`. The error message even tells you that it is trying to do `==` on two `Pair`s and failing.

Note that `std::unique` only removes **consecutive** duplicates. If your container is unsorted (as it will be if you are concatenating two vectors) then you may still have non-consecutive duplicates that are not detected by this check.

It seems like a better idea to use a sorted container , and do a sorted merge instead of concatenation. `map` seems like a much better data structure here.

Comment: thank you! The reason I didn't use map is because we are not allowed to use it as a container for this assignment. We had to use vectors or char arrays. I will try to sort the vectors and then call unique and handle the pair == operator. thanks!